# MySQL - Limit the occurrence one particular value

Tags: mysql

Is there any way for one to limit a column to have a set of particular values be considered as Unique while allowing duplicates for all other values?

An example of what I mean would be having a table with a list of users and each record has a user_group field. The user_group column can only have one occurrence of "Administrator" while allowing all other user groups to appear multiple times.

Right now, I am thinking of creating a trigger that will count the number of occurrences for those values before inserting and updating and block it from occurring by keeping the value the same if it passes the allowed limit. I am wondering if there is an alternative solution to this that would be more efficient.

Comment: Could you split the column into two separate columns?  Then you could have a UNIQUE index on the administrator field.

Comment: the trigger sounds ok